# Does setting a property on a property call the first property's setter?

Tags: objective-c, accessor, declared-property

If a class has a custom setter for a property:

```
@interface OuterClass : NSObject
@property InnerClass *obj;
-(void)setObj:(InnerClass *)obj;
```

and `InnerClass` itself has a property:

```
@property NSString *text;
```

and I then do: `obj.text = @"Hello";` will that activate the `OuterClass` object's `setObj:` method?

Comment: @AndrewMadsen not duplicate

Comment: @JustinMeiners defend your position.  I see your answer and the other one in that linked dupe look remarkably similar in content.

Comment: @CodaFi the question in the link is identical to my first answer (section below BEFORE EDIT) which is asking basically asking if an property does setter and getter. This question is asking if an object with a member gets notified when a members property changes. Different questions about the same functionality in different contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood the context of your original question.

Calling `someObject.obj.text = @"Hello"` will not call `-setObj` on the outer class.

@properties generate simple setters and getters and do not observe changes made to members of ivars.

It will however call `-obj` on `someObject`.

Think of it like this. Given `someObject.obj.text =`, the `someObject.obj` section uses the getter of `someObject` to return `obj`. The `obj.text =` part then sends `-setText` to the result of the `obj` getter.

**BEFORE EDIT:**

Yes, an @property automatically generates a setter and getter for the ivar.

Setting `obj.text = @"hello"` calls the `-setText`: method.

and accessing the property `x = obj.text` calls the `-text` method.

Make sure if you override a setter or getter that the method matches the property exactly.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm using the generated setter (customized). I'm wondering if setting the inner object property will activate the outer object's setObj: method because it's property was modified. I'm aware I'm not explaining myself super well.

Answer (score 4):

No, `setObj:` will not be called because you are not setting the property. You are *getting* the property and then setting one of the result's properties. This is equivalent to `[[something obj] setText:@"Hello"]`.